# How to align caption underneath image

Tags: html, css, layout, caption

I have 9 images in total and three on each row, I have managed to add a caption for one of my images, but failed to do so for the other ones as it just centers everything underneath and not aligned text to rows per image.

```
<figure>
<center>
<img src='images/album1.jpg' alt='missing' />
<figcaption>Album name goes here
<br>Year goes here
<br>artist name goes here</figcaption>

<img src='images/album2.jpg' alt='missing' />
<figcaption>Album name goes here
<br>Year goes here
<br>artist name goes here</figcaption>

<img src='images/album2.jpg' alt='missing' />
<figcaption>Album name goes here
<br>Year goes here
<br>artist name goes here</figcaption>
</figure><center>
```

And so on.

Comment: `<center>` was deprecated about 15 years ago.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I would set up the code this way:

```
<figure>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/200x200' alt='missing' />
    <figcaption>Album name goes here
        <br>Year goes here
        <br>artist name goes here</figcaption>
</figure>
```

and apply the following CSS:

```css
figure {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    margin: 20px; /* adjust as needed */
}
figure img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
figure figcaption {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Because each `figure` is an inline-block, you can basically repeat the unit three times per row, either adding a `<br>` after the every third one, or wrapping three in a block element, or using a CSS3 `nth-of-type(3n)` selector to add a line break or similar.

Use `text-align: center` on `figcaption` to align the test to the center.

See demo at:  http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/4njG8/

The results look like this (for a wide enough screen):

[image]

Comment: This is really in depth Marc. I'm giving it a shot right now and thanks in regards!

Comment: I would like to add that if your figure captions have unequal heights, you you can still align the images by adding `figure { vertical-align: top; ... }`.

Comment: If you have long text (in the "Album name goes here..." ), then this stretches out the image container unfortunately so some hard-coding is required

Comment: Suppose I wanted the first line of images to have only 2 images, and the second line to have 3. For example, maybe the first two belong to one album, the next three belong to another album, and you want everything from an album to be grouped together. Using the code given, a <BR> will not place the third image on a new line but will display it to the side but not aligned with the other two.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me.

```
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  margin: 5px; /* adjust as needed */
}
figure img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
figure figcaption {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

`text-align: center;` is the only thing needed.

Comment: this is actually more general than the current accepted answer, since this will also work if the text is wider than the image.

Answer (score 1):

Each figure should only contain one image and one figcaption.

```
<figure>
    <img>
   <figcaption>
   </figcaption>
</figure>
```

BTW...the 'center' element no longer exists.

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/icpLu)

Comment: You forgot a > after **figvaption** tag.

Comment: I see, I will give it another shot and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Also, what do mean about <center> no longer existing? Is there a better way to implement it or?

Comment: The center tag was deprecated in HTML5

Answer (score 1):

Image caption alignment in **jupyter notebook markdown** cell:
(includes: how to adjust text alignment margins and font style)

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td style='text-align:center;'>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg"
             style='zoom:65%;'> <b> Tree and Sun </b><img>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/21/59/tree-736877__340.jpg" 
             style='zoom:91%;'/>
    <p style='text-align: right; margin-right: 3em; font-family: Serif;'><b> Moon and meow </b></p>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to provide alignment attribute in the **figcaption**: **text-start**, **text-center** and **text-end**

```
<figure>
   <img src='http://placehold.it/150x150' alt='missing' class="figure-img img-fluid rounded-circle"/>
   <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Name</figcaption>
</figure>
```

[image]