# How to align two images in html/css

Tags: html, css, image, figure

So I have two images with captions under them. I want to be able to put them side by side. I've tried in css float: right; and display: inline-block; but I can't simply get it to work. Please and thank you. I'm new to coding.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<figure id="crackers1">
  <img src="crackers2.jpg" alt="missing" height="25%" width="25%" />
  <figcaption>Peppermint Thins</figcaption>
  </figure>
   <figure id="crackers2">
  <img src="crackers2.jpg" alt="missing" height="25%" width="25%" />
  <figcaption>Ritz Crackers</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/hgg9h464/

Comment: sorry but updating my fiddle..plz allow few min.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138758/how-to-align-caption-underneath-image

Comment: is it ok if you will use div span then see this http://jsfiddle.net/hgg9h464/3/

Comment: @YotZin Castrejon check to this http://jsfiddle.net/hgg9h464/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got so many good answers and here's mine also.

If you want to element in same row then you can use **float** or **display:inline-block;**. As per your given example see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgg9h464/6/) or if you are ok with div/span then go with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgg9h464/3/).

Be sure when you are using `float:left` or `float:right` then you have to use `clear:both` after using them so there will be no white space issue but `display:inline-block` is better then float but it depends on user.

Comment: I thank everyone for their great comments it helped a lot. But I believe this one is the best thank you everyone for your input.

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline-block` should do the job. If the two images have different heights, you can add a vertical align.

```
<style>
figure {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top
}
</style>
```

Comment: sorry but check here http://jsfiddle.net/hgg9h464/1/  your code is not working..What wrong m doing?

Comment: thats the same problem i'm having that leo mentioned. It just stays stacked

Answer (score 0):

Write in css style as below..

```
#crackers1,#crackers2 {
 Display:inline-block;
  Width:50%; 
  /* do not write float when using display:inline-block.     */
}

#crackers1 img,#crackers2 img{
   Width:100%;
 }
```

Width:50% would be update as per your requirement.
Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hi now used to this you just created one div in your image parent as like this

```
figure {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin:0;
}
.imGSec{white-space:nowrap;}
```

```css
figure {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin:0;
}
.imGSec{white-space:nowrap;}
```

```html
<div class="imGSec">
<figure id="crackers1">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8q3x_pFvnepIe7b7C_YeHbbHJe4n1KXKPIgldpccJY1hw3Z8z" alt="missing" height="25%" width="25%" />
  <figcaption>Peppermint Thins</figcaption>
  </figure>
   <figure id="crackers2">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdNkStSLeNk_3eAN6MV7asaOQapylITCIxs1JDOEblIc8V4eqy" alt="missing" height="25%" width="25%" />
  <figcaption>Ritz Crackers</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you please share why there is space between those images?