# How center text underneath images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to center text underneath images. The images and text in question are in the [passphrase generator at this site](https://actionscript.no/passwords). I have tried simply adding a `<br>` in between the images and the text, different display properties, the bottom and top properties, changing flex direction on the text alone, probably more that I can't remember at this time.
[This is the JS](https://actionscript.no/passphrase.js) just in case there is something wrong with the way im generating the images and text.
All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The lock it the background makes it really uncomfortable to read, maybe you could make it a little bit more transperant

Comment: someone asked the same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138758/how-to-align-caption-underneath-image

Comment: @kazura , solution that you be marked don't work in IE9 ,IE8 ,IE7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to wrap your images and phrases in a figure element to break the layout of the parent that has `display: flex;`. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvmwvat5/2/) for a quick reference.

Answer (score 1):

You use figure and figcaption elements from html5

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://www.innomate.com/application/files/4514/8474/3363/front01.png" />
    <figcaption>Testing</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Here is fiddle to demonstrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/twk3abom/

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap each `<img>` and `<p>` tags inside a `<div>`. That should do the trick.

So it should look like this,

```
<div>
    <img>
    <p></p>
</div>
<div>
    <img>
    <p></p>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put each element in a `<div>` nothing else to change.

This would look like this on HTML:

```
<div id="passphraseBilder">
    <div>
        <img>
        <p>bowling</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img>
        <p>doughnut</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img>
        <p>calculator</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```css
 div {
      width: 200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
 }

 img {
      width: 100%;
 }

 p {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #000;
        margin: 1px 1px 2px 1px;
   }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRJqYSNS-A4_Vd8CptMrxXbIFS3q1HaHPHZSnscG1iNSMmrMKRS">
    <p>Flowers</p>
   
 </div>
```